# Rolling rank for observations from t-k to t-1 in Stata using rangestat

Tags: stata

I have a panel data set that looks like this:

```
ID   Time   Income
1    1      20
1    2      15
1    3      30
1    4      10
1    5      40
1    6      22
1    7      18
1    8      35
1    9      16
1    10     26
1    11     50
1    12     17
1    13     18
```

...

```
2    1      19
2    2      44
```

...

And I want to generate a new variable called "Ave_Rank", which is obtained in this method:

1. For each ID, for observations with Time > 10, rank previous 10 (t-10
   to t-1) Incomes; with largest receiving a rank of 10, and smallest
   receiving a rank of 1.
2. Ave_Rank is the average rank of Incomes at
       t-1, t-3, t-5, t-7, t-9.

Examples:

At t = 11
[Ave_Rank = (7+9+6+1+2) / 5 = 5]

```
ID   Time   Income   Rank   Ave_Rank
1    1      20       5       
1    2      15       2
1    3      30       8
1    4      10       1
1    5      40       10
1    6      22       6
1    7      18       4
1    8      35       9
1    9      16       3
1    10     26       7
1    11     50              5
```

At t = 12
[Ave_Rank = (10+3+4+9+7) / 5 = 6.6]

```
ID   Time   Income   Rank   Ave_Rank     
1    2      15       2
1    3      30       7
1    4      10       1
1    5      40       9
1    6      22       5
1    7      18       4
1    8      35       8
1    9      16       3
1    10     26       6
1    11     50       10          
1    12     17              6.6
```

I know a (lengthy) method that would work is to generate lags (from 1 to 10) using:

```
tsset ID Time
gen income1 = l.Income
gen income1 = l2.Income
```

...

```
gen income10 = l10.Income
```

Then reshape from wide to long:

```
reshape long income, i(ID_Time) j(time_lag)
```

Then generate rank for each ID_Time:

```
bys ID_Time: egen income_rank = rank(income)
```

Then finally, generate the desired Ave_Rank variable:

```
by ID_Time: egen Ave_Rank = mean(income_rank) if time_lag == 1 | time_lag == 3 | time_lag == 5 |time_lag == 7 |time_lag == 9
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to complete the task using rangestat (or a combination of Mata and rangestat).

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `rangestat` won't do anything so _ad hoc_ so far as I can see. The closest I can think of is your own program plus `rangerun'. Both are from SSC. (Here, just as on Statalist, it helps to flag community-contributed commands.)

Comment: @NickCox I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick has pointed out, you can do this with `rangerun` (from SSC) . For each observation, `rangerun` will run the `even_rank` program using a dataset that includes only the observations that fall within the desired 10 period window. The `even_rank` program orders the observations by `income`, reduces the data to even observations (t-1 is the 10th observation) and then calculates the mean.

```
clear all

* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(id time income)
1  1 20
1  2 15
1  3 30
1  4 10
1  5 40
1  6 22
1  7 18
1  8 35
1  9 16
1 10 26
1 11 50
1 12 17
1 13 18
end
isid id time, sort

program even_rank
    if _N < 10 exit
    sort income time
    gen rank = _n
    sort time
    keep if mod(_n,2) == 0
    sum rank, meanonly
    gen Ave_Rank = r(mean)
    drop rank
end
rangerun even_rank, by(id) interval(time -10 -1) verbose
```